# Cannot modify header information error in Codeigniter - Google App Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I'm getting the following error in codeigniter once I deploy it in server. I do not get this error in localhost. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions. I'm using Google Apps Engine.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object 
in /base/data/home/apps/s~some-app/1.401263586523638658/application/models/Some_model.php on line 199
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /base/data/home/apps/s~some-app/1.401263586523638658/application/models/Some_model.php:199)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 569

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Filename: models/Some_model.php

Line Number: 199

Backtrace:
```

I checked the controller and models for any white space and I do not have any such. This particular function is also not used by any cron job as mentioned in another post.

Edited to add code:

```
$query = "select u.id, u.queue_name, u.queue_email, u.tickets_for_all  
                    from agent_queue_mapping_table as m, queue_table as u 
                    where u.id=m.queue_id 
                    and u.company_id = ".$this->session->userdata('user_comp_id')." 
                    and m.user_id = ".$this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $queue_details = $this->db->query($query);                       
    return $queue_details->result_array();
```

Comment: It's the first error message that's being sent to the browser (that's why you're getting the "headers already sent") after that. You need to check the error _"Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object "_. For us to be able to help you, we need to see that code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have 2 user roles. Both the riles when logging in are getting the same error but the model remains different for both. One common thing between both models is they both use session variables however there is nothing wrong with the session variables.

Comment: We still need to see the code. Start with the piece you're having issues with in your question. It's hard for us to help if we don't know what the code looks like.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have updated the question with my code.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check the PHP version of your server.

2.Get your SQL query by using $this->db->last_query() and run the query on MySQL console and check if there any errors.

3.Check the result_array() array function usage in your controller. send us your screenshot of the code here to check on that section

Comment: This is just three comments (specially since you're asking for additional info). Comments should be written as comments under the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, because I had not updated a table that I had to alter. Once I did that, this issue got resolved.